# dojo equivalent of jquery ajaxPrefilter

Tags: ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I need to intercept outgoing ajax calls from a library I use, that uses dojo. In jQuery I could just use [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) is there a dojo equivalent?

I have tried using the registry, but that requires that ajax requests are made using `registry.post` or some such thing and I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dojo/aspect](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html) for this. In fact the `aspect.before` example uses xhr as its example: [dojo/aspect - .before](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html#before)